# Using listings morecomment option to color code up to the end of the line

Tags: listings

I use the following code to color my shell statements:

```
\lstdefinestyle{sh}{
  breaklines=false,
  language=sh,
  commentstyle=\color{cyan},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  stringstyle=\color{purple},
  identifierstyle=\color{black},
  morecomment=[n][\color{red}]{\ -}{\ },
}
```

But something unexpected happened:

```
$ ./configure --foo
$ make
```

It color the `--foo` successfully, but it also color the `$` in front of `make`. I know that is because the end of comment is defined to `<space>`, LaTeX color the `$`.

But I don't want this coloring? It there a solution to such case?

Or, I know that it may be possible to use a option like: `morecomment=[n][\color{red}]{\ -}{<newline>}`. But I don't know what to put in the position of `<newline>`.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided a complete MWE, I hope this solution works also in your own document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    language=bash,
    showstringspaces=false,
    morecomment=[s][\color{red}]{\ -}{\ },
    otherkeywords={$},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
$ ./configure --foo       
$ make
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add an extra space after the options, I see two alternatives:

```
morecomment = [n][\color{red}]{\ -}{\^^M}
```

This is your original version, where `^^M` is the end-of-line character as closing delimiter.

```
morecomment = [l][\color{red}]{\ -}
```

This defines a new line comment which spans to the end of the line. If you don't want nested highlighting in the options part, I would prefer this version.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstdefinestyle{sh}{
  breaklines=false,
  language=sh,
  identifierstyle=\color{black},
%  morecomment=[n][\color{red}]{\ -}{\ },
}
\lstset{
  style=sh,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\color{gray}\footnotesize
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[morecomment={[n][\color{red}]{\ -}{\^^M}}]
$ ./configure --foo
$ make
$ ./foo -f -o blah
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[morecomment={[l][\color{red}]{\ -}}]
$ ./configure --foo
$ make
$ ./foo -f -o blah
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

outputs

[image]